# How to add a point to an already created polygon in google maps v3 when a user clicks on the border of that polygon

Tags: events, google-maps, border, polygon

After a user draws a polygon on my map I want them to be able to add points to it if desired. Perhaps it would be nice to have some kind of hover event to show when they were over the line and could add a point (but that isn't necessary). The only thing I can think of is to add separate lines for each edge. Looking at the api I was hoping to find some kind of border clicked but didn't come up with anything.

Has anyone else run into this and found a good solution other than the one I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to make the Polygon editable:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#editable

Comment: This link doesnt have much in it